# if start a new thread in main(), then invoke wait() can`t block the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

just see the code

```
static class ThreadA extends Thread {
    public ThreadA(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " call notify()");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadA t1 = new ThreadA("t1");

    synchronized (t1) {
        System.out.println("start:  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t1.start();

        t1.wait();
        System.out.println(" -- end -- ");
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
start:  main
t1 call notify()
 -- end --
```

why invoke wait() does not block the main thread

Comment: It is blocking the main thread, but it is getting released somehow. It might have to do with the main thread being the last thread, because t1 will finish executing.

Comment: but, if i just invoke wait inside the synchronized bolck,it will block the main thread.@matt

Comment: Yes, the main thread gets blocked, then your other thread runs, then the main thread gets woken for some reason. This is why it is recommended against using wait, because there can be spurious wakeups. Hence the while loop suggestion or the `join` suggestion.

Comment: thank u for your answer, but i want to know the exact reason

Comment: When the thread completes it gets notified. Lock on a different object and main will continue to block.

Comment: @matt yeah, u are right, thanks a lot.

Comment: But keep in mind that, while in this specific scenario, it is known that `Thread` internally calls `notifyAll()` on itself, you always have to be prepared for so-called “spurious wakeups” when calling `wait()`, so returning from `wait` is never sufficient to assume that the awaited condition has been fulfilled. You must re-check.

Comment: yeah，i will remember that,thanks @Holger

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question can be found in the javadoc of the [`join(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) method :

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. **As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked.** It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

(emphasis mine)

So : your main loop stops waiting, as the thread it's waiting on calls `notifyAll` on itself as it finishes.

As others have pointed out already, the proper way to wait for a thread to finish is to call `join`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `Thread.join()`. The purpose of `Object.wait()` is to wait until the monitor lock on that object to be released by another Thread (using `Object.notify()` or `Object.notifyAll()`).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ThreadA t1 = new ThreadA("t1");

    synchronized (t1) {
        System.out.println("start:  " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        t1.start();

        t1.join();
        System.out.println(" -- end -- ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it odd, that in this example `notify` is getting called? Do threads notify when they complete? Does it have to do with leaving a synchronized block?

Comment: i just want to know why the main thread is not block, as far as i know, unless invoke notify/notifyAll, current thread will block after wait()

Comment: Wait and join has different use purpose. Join will wait until interruption or joined threads run block to finish. But wait finishes when a notfy is getted. There is no exception throws and programmer knows there is a different thread status.

Comment: @chasel it is block until the thread `t1` ends. As the reason of this notify, I didn't have found any documentation yet but it will work the same as `join` in that case.